# Accelerometer with BounceEase

Tags: xaml, animation, accelerometer, windows-phone

I have a Rectangle on my Windows Phone page. When the user tilts their phone, the position of the Rectangle is changed (I use a TranslateTransform) based on the tilt. It works fine.

Like this:

```
void CurrentValueChanged(object sender,
    SensorReadingEventArgs<AccelerometerReading> e)
{
    // respond to the accelerometer on the UI thread
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        // left, right
        var _LeftDelta = e.SensorReading.Acceleration.X * 5d;
        var _NewLeft = m_Transform.X + _LeftDelta;
        var _PanelWidth = ContentPanel.RenderSize.Width;
        var _RectangleWidth = m_Rectangle.RenderSize.Width;
        if (_NewLeft > 0 && _NewLeft < _PanelWidth - _RectangleWidth)
            m_Transform.X = _NewLeft;

        // up, down
        var _RightDelta = e.SensorReading.Acceleration.Y * -5d;
        var _NewTop = m_Transform.Y + _RightDelta;
        var _PanelHeight = ContentPanel.RenderSize.Height;
        var _RectangleHeight = m_Rectangle.RenderSize.Height;
        if (_NewTop > 0 && _NewTop < _PanelHeight - _RectangleHeight)
            m_Transform.Y = _NewTop;
    }));
}
```

What I would like to do, though, is add a bounce when the user hits the side of the page.

Anyone know how?

Answer (score 1):

Your current code does not have acceleration separated from velocity.

the velocity should be updated based on the acceleration, rather than updating locations based on the acceleration. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceleration

Your value 5d takes the place of the mass. it tells you how much is happening for a given force.

You need to keep variables for location

x,y

and velocity

v_x , v_y

then update the locations with

```
x <-  x+ v_x* step_size
y <-  y+ v_y* step_size
```

and update the velocity:

```
v_x <-  v_x + acceletation_x* 5d * step_size
v_y <-  v_y + acceletation_y* 5d * step_size
```

Now, a bounce is trivial. When you reach an upper or lower edge, just flip the sign of the velocity: v_y -> -v_y, and for hitting a side, v_x -> -v_x.

You can make the bounce-back slower than the original velocity by multiplying with a constant when bouncing, for example v_x -> -v_x*0.7
will make the bounce velocity 70% of the initial speed.

You may also require some friction or things will just bounce around forever. Either you learn and implement some real model for that or just use some dummy way to slightly reduce the velocity in each step. The simplest thing that could give something like this is, in each step:

```
v_x <-  v_x * 0.95
v_y <-  v_y * 0.95
```

Comment: You managed to find the two similar questions and answer them both. Thank you for your input. Your solution, however, isn't where I was hoping you would go. I was looking for how to dynamically apply an easing out function.